# How to parse json in my view from a requests post

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I have the following requests code:

```
>>> data
{'AmountInUSD': '40', 'CreditCardLastFourDigits': '1111'}
>>> r=requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/balance/deposit/', data=data)
```

Here is how I am trying to parse the json, but I keep getting an `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`:

```
def deposit(request):
    print '***', request.POST
    print '>>>', request.raw_post_data
    print '###', request.body
    json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
```

And it prints:

```
*** <QueryDict: {u'AmountInUSD': [u'40'], u'CreditCardLastFourDigits': [u'1111']}>
>>> AmountInUSD=40&CreditCardLastFourDigits=1111
### AmountInUSD=40&CreditCardLastFourDigits=1111
```

How should I be doing this instead?

Comment: Is data a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the incoming request has already been converted to a *`QueryDict`*, it is not a json string which is why `json.loads` cannot do anything with it.

The reason its a `QueryDict` is because you passed the dictionary to `requests.post` and it correctly posted it as part of the request body as form-encoded data.

As its a `QueryDict` object, you can access it just like a Python dictionary:

```
request.POST.get('AmountInUSD')
request.POST.get('CreditCardLastFourDigits')
```

If you want to convert it back to json, try `json.dumps(request.POST)`, or modify the requests code to convert the dictionary into a json string before sending it:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/balance/deposit/',
              data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: I need to do an `HMAC` based on the user's body data.

Answer (score 1):

Requests POSTs `data` as form-encoded data. That's what you get in `deposit`. If you want to post JOSN, encode `data` before posting.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```